# ffmpeg combine overlay and adding sound command

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, overlay

I am using the following command to add audio on a video

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i test.mp3 -filter:a atempo=2.0 -c:v copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest output.mp4
```

I am using the following command to add an overlay on a video

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i overlay.gif -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v] -shortest -map [v] -map 0:a? -ac 2 output.mp4
```

How can I merge these two commands together ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i overlay.gif -i test.mp3 -filter_complex [1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay=shortest=1[v] -map [v] -map 2:a:0 -filter:a atempo=2.0 -ac 2 -shortest output.mp4`

Comment: Thanks for answering , but the thing is it increase the video length upoto audio length , what I really wanted the audio length should be equal to video length.

Comment: Edited overlay filter args.

Comment: Thanks u saved my day